# Unscope scoped css style for selected module

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've been trying **not** apply a scoped style for one certain element in the DOM hierarchy.

The use case is that I want to apply the style defined in the parent page's theme inside a widget for specific elements.

```css
      body {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style: normal;
        color: #2b2b2b;
        background: white;
        line-height: 1.65;
      }

      button {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        background-color: green;
      }

      .scope {}

      .reset {
        composes: scope;
      }

      .reset div,
      .reset button {
        font-size: 32pt;
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      .reset button {
        background-color: blue;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Unscope scope</title>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194)">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button type="button">
      Standard style button
    </button>
    <div id="app" class="reset">
      <div>
        <button type="button">
          Scope style button
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="unscoped">
          Unscoped style button
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is how I want it too look like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) pseudo class in CSS to make sure you only apply your style to elements without the selector inside.

This is what that would look like in your case:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: #2b2b2b;
  background: white;
  line-height: 1.65;
}

button {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  background-color: green;
}

.scope {}

.reset {
  composes: scope;
  /* ^ I don't think this is valid CSS or at least I've never seen this */
}

.reset button:not(.unscoped) {
  /*          ^ See the change here */
  font-size: 32pt;
  background-color: blue;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Unscope scope</title>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194)">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <button type="button">
      Standard style button
    </button>
    <div id="app" class="reset">
      <div>
        <button type="button">
          Scope style button
        </button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="button" class="unscoped">
          Unscoped style button
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's the way I finally went with. Thanks!